# Python Multithreading Async Flask Return

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, flask, process

I have a queue (rabbitmq with pika) which a producer/manager puts problems into and then many workers each come and solve those problems in parallel, one problem per worker.  The original manager later asynchronously looks at an output queue that the workers put the results into and decides how to put these into my database.  Right now the manager is the start and the end of the processing.  This is already fine and working but a few days ago I wanted to add an API endpoint which would return an answer for a specific problem and I don't want to tear up the queue and many worker paradigm.

To do this, I want to make a Flask endpoint which catches the API calls and puts the problem into the queue. A different thread needs to be monitoring the output queue and see when the problem is finished the communicate to the original thread the answer so that it can return to the original caller and finish the API call.  I need multithreading so that new requests can come in while we wait for the answer to be computed.  Am I going about this the wrong way from a design perspective?  If not, how can I do threading with Flask in this way?  Thanks.

Comment: Actually keeping API call until worker's job is finished is not a good practice. In my previous experience, to process API call that is followed by long-time computing I've been assigning an id to a job and returning it as a result of this API call, so client can check status and get results using this id.

Comment: Interesting and good advice.  So you are saying instead of a slow API return give a promise that the client could poll to see if it is done instead? I'll definitely consider that

Comment: Yes, some kind of promise.

Comment: Look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) + [Flower](http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)